# R shiny-app DT: apply filters using greater than

Tags: r, filter, shiny, dt

I'm building a shiny-app using R and, within the app, I need to display a table that has the possibility to apply filters to numeric, character and factor columns.

I'm using the DT package and this is an example of the code:

```
# packages
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
    br(),
    DT::dataTableOutput("my_iris")
)

# server
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$my_iris <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(
            data = iris,
            filter = list(
                position = "top",
                clear = FALSE,
                plain = TRUE
            )
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem is that I need to apply filters to numeric columns like "Sepal.Length > 5" and I can't accomplish that using simply the scrollbar implemented in DT since, if I move the scrollbar, then the filters applied is like [5,b] while I simply want a filter like (5,b).

Is there an easy way to accomplish that using R and DT?

EDIT: I think that maybe my problem could be solved using the options of [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/), i.e. the Javascript library used to implement the filters, but I don't know which options to modify and how to implement the changes in DT.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is and old post, but just in case it helps to someone, I found a way to do it. It may not be the best solution or the solution that the @agila was trying to find.. but here it is.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(12,
                   DTOutput('table')
            )
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$table <- renderDT(iris,
                                 filter = "top",
                                 options = list(
                                     pageLength = 5
                                 )
        )
    }
)
```

Here you have like a range to select your data depending on the filters that you want to put.

[image]

The original source is from [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-displaying-datatable-with-filter-option-for-each-column/33800)

Comment: Hi Eva! Thank you very much for your answer but I don't understand how it does solve my problem. Can you add more details? I still don't understand how to select only those rows that satisfy a condition like _Sepal.Length > 5_.